# Pyspark How to update all null values from all column in a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have below DF with null values in some columns.

Now I need to update/replace those 'null' values with 'NA'

```
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
|Product|Canada|China|Mexico| USA|
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
| Orange|  null| 4000|  null|4000|
|  Beans|  null| 1500|  2000|1600|
| Banana|  2000|  400|  null|1000|
|Carrots|  2000| 1200|  null|1500|
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
```

I found the method 'fillna' to replace the null value

however I need to update/replace all column having null values

So something like this or better way

```
replaced = df.fillna({str(col):'NA', col for col in df.columns})
```

Appreciate any help to get the right approach

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of these columns (other than product)? Can you add the schema?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`subset()`** and pass the column name in order fill with Null values

**`df = df.fillna(0, subset=['Canada', 'China', 'Mexico', 'USA'])`**

or , in case if you want to use **`fillna()`** for all the columns , pass them in a **`dictionary`** , also you can specify your choice :)

**`df = df.fillna({'Canada':'4', 'China': '5', 'Mexico' : '6', 'USA': '7})`**

Or, you can simply use below to fill all the columns with null values

**`df = df.fillna("a_value")`**

Comment: Hi @dsk.. i tried all the way you suggested, but none of those  giving output as expected.. it was still retuning with null value

Comment: Can you try converting to StringType and fill with na. and check

Comment: let me know please where i supposed to convert to a string...

Comment: df = df.withColumn("Canada", F.col(Canada).cast(T.StringType())) - try this